# Windows 10, Office365, Powerpoint "Access denied, contact your administrator" while opening a PowerPoint-file from a net drive

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

We are using Windows 10 and Office365.

A user has the problem, that he can not open Powerpoint-files by doubleclicking them from a net drive.
If he doubleclicks a Powerpoint-file the error is shown. (Access denied, contact your administrator)
For other users, with the same group and rights on the folders, it is still working to open  Powerpoint-files by doubleclicking them.

---

What I have done:
I checked the rights. -> All have the same.

I duplicated the group, removed and readded all the rights. -> Problem still is the same.

I found a workarround, but we want to have the normal behavior.

---

Workarround:
Start PowerPoint->Open->Search->Direct to the desired file->Select the file->Open

This works to open the Powerpoint-files.

---

---

EDIT:

Repairing Office did not help.

With a temp account he can open the files. But changeing accounts is no option for us.

Comment: From what you're saying it seems clear the problem is somehow connected to this one user's user account. If you create a temporary account for this user, does the problem go away?

Comment: Yes this shoud work since it is only this one use which is affected.

Comment: If it does, the easiest would be just making that temp account permanent for that user. I'm not putting this as an answer yet as changing to a new user account isn't always a straight-forward job - another community member might know a different solution. Please test to confirm if it does work, and update your question with the result.

Comment: Did this user try to open presentations via the UNC path? Besides, does this issue occur with other files other than Office files?